# How to fetch objects from arraylist and set on text view

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a quiz app and want to fetch objects from array list an set on text view. I want to change the content of text view as well as radio buttons on the click of button. I have tried every possible way to do that but I still can't make it work.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButton;
Button btnnext;
int id,j;
Questions q1,q2,q3,q4,q;
ArrayList<Questions> list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ques);
    radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg1);
    btnnext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    id=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(id);
    q1=new Questions();
    q1.setQues("Ques 1.What is the full form of SMTP?");
    q1.setOption1("Simple Mail Transfer Protocol");
    q1.setOption2("Simple Mail Text Person");
    q1.setOption3("Simple Message Transfer Protocol");
    q1.setOption4("Sound Mail Text Pattern");

    q2=new Questions();
    q2.setQues("Ques 2.What is the full form of TCP?");
    q2.setOption1("Transfer Control Protocol");
    q2.setOption2("Text Control Protocol");
    q2.setOption3("Transfer Communication Person");
    q2.setOption4("Text Control Person");

    q3=new Questions();
    q3.setQues("Ques 3.What DNS stands for?");
    q3.setOption1("Domain Name System");
    q3.setOption2("Domain Name Server");
    q3.setOption3("Distributed Name Server");
    q3.setOption4("Distributed Name System");

    q4=new Questions();
    q4.setQues("Ques 4.What is a port?");
    q4.setOption1("Numbered Socket");
    q4.setOption2("Protocol");
    q4.setOption3("Server");
    q4.setOption4("Path");
    list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(q1);
    list.add(q2);
    list.add(q3);
    list.add(q4);

    String one=q1.getQues();
    tv.setText(one);
    ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(0)).setText(q1.getOption1());
    ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(1)).setText(q1.getOption2());
    ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(2)).setText(q1.getOption3());
    ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(3)).setText(q1.getOption4());
    String Ques[]=new String[4];

   /* for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        Questions q=list.get(i);
        tv.setText(q.getQues());
    }*/
   btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            while(j<=list.size()){
                q=list.get(j);
                tv.setText(q.getQues());
                j++;
            }

        }
    });

}
}
Questions.java
public class Questions {

private String ques;
private String option1;
private String option2;
private String option3;
private String option4;

public String getQues() {
    return ques;
}

public void setQues(String ques) {
    this.ques = ques;
}

public String getOption1() {
    return option1;
}

public void setOption1(String option1) {
    this.option1 = option1;
}

public String getOption2() {
    return option2;
}

public void setOption2(String option2) {
    this.option2 = option2;
}

public String getOption3() {
    return option3;
}

public void setOption3(String option3) {
    this.option3 = option3;
}

public String getOption4() {
    return option4;
}

public void setOption4(String option4) {
    this.option4 = option4;
}
}

main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Test Paper 1"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/test"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/queslay">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:padding="18dip"
        android:id="@+id/ques"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"></TextView>
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rg1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rg1ansl"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rg1ans2"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rg1ans3"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rg1ans4"
            />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/queslay"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/queslay"
    android:text="Previous"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all use constructor of your model
make `int count =0;` asa global variable

```
     public Questions(String ques, String option1, String option2, String option3, String option4) {
            this.ques = ques;
            this.option1 = option1;
            this.option2 = option2;
            this.option3 = option3;
            this.option4 = option4;
        }


and get your data on depend on the count 
then on click of the next button click on count

      btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(count<=list.size()){

                    count++;
                    setQuestion();
                }

            }
        });
public void setQuestion(){
 tv.setText(list.get(count).getQuestion());
((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(0)).setText(list.get(count).getOption1());
    ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(1)).setText(list.get(count).getOption2());
    ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(2)).setText(list.get(count).getOption3());
    ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(3)).setText(list.get(count).getOption4());
}
```

and in `setQuestion()` set your textview and radio button content and call `setQuestion()` in `onCreate()` for 0 position question

Comment: Thanks for the help @Avinash. "get your data on depend on the count " how to do this.I am new to android.

Comment: just make a global(field) variable int count =0;